# How to merge multiple files which are not in order and assign the name of file to a specific column in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, cat, join, merge

I have around 250 `.gtf` files. Here I'm showing 3 `.gtf` files. All the `.gtf` files have three columns that look like below:

```
TUSCC120A.gtf
TUSCC36.gtf
TUSCC89B.gtf
```

`TUSCC120A.gtf` looks like below:

```
transcript MSTRG.6968.1 0.000000
transcript MSTRG.6968.2 1.000000
transcript MSTRG.6975.2 0.000000
transcript ENST00000446 3.000000
transcript ENST00000432 0.000000
```

`TUSCC36.gtf` looks like below:

```
transcript ENST00000446 3.456000
transcript MSTRG.6968.2 1.342000
transcript MSTRG.6968.1 0.000000
transcript MSTRG.6975.2 4.000000
transcript ENST00000432 5.000000
```

`TUSCC89B.gtf` looks like below:

```
transcript MSTRG.6975.2 2.213000
transcript MSTRG.6968.2 4.342000
transcript ENST00000432 2.000000
transcript ENST00000446 0.000000
transcript MSTRG.6968.1 3.000000
```

As you see the second column, has names that are in a different order in all 3 `.gtf` files. I'm trying to merge all three gtf files. I tried with `paste`

```
paste TUSCC120A.gtf TUSCC36.gtf TUSCC89B.gtf > output.txt
```

`output.txt` looks like:

```
transcript MSTRG.6968.1 0.000000         transcript ENST00000446 3.456000        transcript MSTRG.6975.2 2.213000
transcript MSTRG.6968.2 0.000000         transcript MSTRG.6968.2 1.342000        transcript MSTRG.6968.2 4.342000
transcript MSTRG.6975.2 0.000000         transcript MSTRG.6968.1 0.000000        transcript ENST00000432 2.000000
transcript ENST00000446 0.000000        transcript MSTRG.6975.2 4.000000        transcript ENST00000446 0.000000
transcript ENST00000432 0.000000        transcript ENST00000432 5.000000        transcript MSTRG.6968.1 3.000000
```

I want the output to be looked like below:

```
ID               target_Ids        TUSCC120A            TUSCC36       TUSCC89B
transcript      MSTRG.6968.1       0.000000            0.000000        3.000000
transcript      MSTRG.6968.2       1.000000            1.342000        4.342000
transcript      MSTRG.6975.2       0.000000            4.000000        2.213000
transcript      ENST00000446      3.000000            3.456000        0.000000
transcript      ENST00000432      0.000000            5.000000        2.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat -f tst.awk
BEGIN {
    header = "id" FS "target_id"
}

FNR == 1 { 
    f = FILENAME
    sub(/\.gtf/,"",f)
    header = header FS f
}

{
    row[$2] = (FNR==NR ? $0 : row[$2] FS $3)
}

END {
    print header
    for (x in row) print row[x]
}
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.gtf
id target_id TUSCC120A TUSCC36 TUSCC89B
transcript MSTRG.6968.1 0.000000 0.000000 3.000000
transcript MSTRG.6975.2 0.000000 4.000000 2.213000
transcript MSTRG.6968.2 1.000000 1.342000 4.342000
transcript ENST00000446 3.000000 3.456000 0.000000
transcript ENST00000432 0.000000 5.000000 2.000000
```

Comment: If you have any different delimiter, like '\t'(tab), include into the `BEGIN` statement `FS = "\t"`

Comment: Hey this looks working, but there is a problem....I have duplicates in the second column of my files. So, for example, in my output file it looks like this `transcript MSTRG.169775 0.219360 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.317084 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.140959 0.033214`

Comment: I have tested with your example and it works fine.